# ons-gesture-detectorで捕捉したイベントの発生元DOMを取得したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

monaca+onsen-ui初心者です。

ons-gesture-detectorであるページでのタップ操作のイベントを補足して、そのイベント発生元ページのDOMをJavescriptで操作したいのですが、DOMを取得するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか?

イベントハンドラ内でdocumentやイベントオブジェクトをダンプしてみたのですが、
対象のDOMが見つかりませんでした。

具体的にはmonacaの最小限のUIテンプレートなどで、page1.htmlで発生したイベントをindex.htmlで補足し、page1.htmlのDOMを取得して操作する、といったことを想定しております。

稚拙で申し訳ないのですが、以下にサンプルコードを載せてみます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<!-- page1.html -->
<ons-gesture-detector>
  <div id="hoge">hoge</div>
</ons-gesture-detector>

<!-- index.html -->
<script>
  // イベントハンドラ
  $(document).on("tap", "#hoge", function(){
    // ここでpage1.htmlのDOMを取得して操作したい
  });
</script>
```